# Category ids, where are they defined in the admin?

Tags: category, admin

I'm having some trouble finding the category id of the categories I'm examining.  Where are they defined in the admin?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In admin you can see the category Id after click on the category. You can not change the Category ID if that is what you are trying to do.

See screen shot. [image]

Comment: that's ridiculous.  on my testing platform i will have to continuously update code to reflect the live site because of category id inconsistencies.

Comment: You don't want to be putting in production database entries in your dev site.

Comment: Yes, but i'm storing category information within a cookie that fetches a variety of products.  So, in order to make alterations to this live site feature I will have to alter a ton of code in order to even see it function on my dev.  Well, not a ton, but you catch my drift.

Answer (score 3):

The ids are autogenerated. the id is the autoincrement PK of the table `catalog_category_entity`.
You should be able to see the category id when editing the category in the backend. It is near the category name, above the edit form.

Comment: thanks. although i'm now stuck between a hard place and a magento.